# express res.redirect() is not working in login

Tags: typescript, express, webserver, multer, body-parser

Supposed I want the server will link user to the admin.html page after login successfully so I use put res.redirect('/admin.html') inside the '/login' route handler (POST method).

However, the server does not direct user to to the admin.html page. The server will only redirect user to stay in the main page (route "/") every time user clicks the login button after inputting username and password. It cannot redirect me to go to the `admin.html` page.

The admin.html is stored in "protected" folder and I have already apply app.use(isLoggedIn, express.static('protected')) so the server should be supposed to be able to access it.

p.s. user.json is used to store user username and password info.

```
import express, {NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import expressSession from "express-session";
import path from "path";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import jsonfile from "jsonfile";
import multer from "multer";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.resolve("./public/uploads"));
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}.${file.mimetype.split("/")[1]}`);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

const app = express();

app.use(
  expressSession({
    secret: "Memo wall is fantastic",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

interface Memo {
  content: String;
  image: String;
}

interface User {
    username: String;
    password: String;
  }


app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (req.session["counter"]) {
    req.session["counter"] += 1;
  } else {
    req.session["counter"] = 1;
  }
  console.log(`req.session['counter'] is ${req.session["counter"]}`);
  next();
});

app.use(function(req: Request, res: Response, next:NextFunction){
    const now = new Date();
    // const date = now.toISOString().replace('T','').replace(/\..*/g,'');
    const date = formatDate(now);
    console.log(`[${date}] Request ${req.path}`);
    next();

});

app.post("/memos", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  const memos = await jsonfile.readFile("./memos.json");
  const memo = req.body;
  if (req.file) {
    memo.image = req.file.filename;
  }
  memos.push(memo);
  await jsonfile.writeFile("./memos.json", memos, { spaces: 4 });
  // memos.push(req.body);
  // console.log(req.body)
  res.redirect("/"); //URL vs file path
  // memos.push(req.body);
});

app.get("/memos", async (req, res) => {
  const q = req.query.q;
  const memos: Memo[] = await jsonfile.readFile("./memos.json");
  if (!q) {
    res.json(memos);
  } else {
    const filteredMemos = memos.filter((memo) => memo.content.includes(q +''));
    res.json(filteredMemos);
  }
});

app.post('/login', async(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    const users:User[] = await jsonfile.readFile("./users.json");
    const userFound = users.find(function(user){
        return user.username === req.body.username 
        && user.password === req.body.password;
    })
    if(userFound){
        req.session['user'] = userFound;
        res.redirect('/admin.html');
    }else{
        res.redirect('/');
    }

});


const isLoggedIn = (req:Request,res:Response,next:express.NextFunction)=>{

    if(req.session['user']){
        next();
    }else{
       res.redirect('/');

    }
}


app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(isLoggedIn, express.static('protected'));


app.use(function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("./public/404.html"));
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log("Listening at http://localhost:8080");
});

function formatDate(now:Date){
    return now.getFullYear()+"-"+
           (now.getMonth()+1 +"").padStart(2,"0") + "-" +
            (now.getDate()+"").padStart(2,"0")+" "+
            (now.getHours()+"").padStart(2,"0")+":"+
            (now.getMinutes()+"").padStart(2,"0")+":"+
            (now.getSeconds()+"").padStart(2,"0");
}
```

Comment: So, what happens when you do `res.redirect('/admin.html')` in response to the `/login` route?  And, where is any of that code?  There's no code shown here for either the `/login` or the `/admin.html` routes which seem like the code we most need to see, along with you explaining what you observe when you try the redirect.

Comment: res.redirect('/admin.html') in the login route supposedly direct user to admin.html after successful login and the admin html is just simple page showing the text "This is admin page."

Comment: @jfriend00 The code related to /login and the /admin.html is already shown. You need to scroll the whole code to see them.

Comment: @jfriend00  app.post('/login', async(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    const users:User[] = await jsonfile.readFile("./users.json");
    const userFound = users.find(function(user){
        return user.username === req.body.username 
        && user.password === req.body.password;
    })
    if(userFound){
        req.session['user'] = userFound;
        res.redirect('/admin.html');
    }else{
        res.redirect('/');
    }

});

Comment: I didn't see the code below that you have to scroll to.  So, what do you see in the browser after you login and redirect  to `/admin.html`?  What happens?  And, what route are you expecting to serve `/admin.html`?

Comment: @jfriend00 I just want to let server to direct user to an html page called admin.html after user inputs correct username & password and the admin.html only shows a text "This is the admin page." I am expecting to the route `app.post(' /login')` will redirect user to `/admin.html` after login successfully.

Comment: And, what DOES happen when you do the redirect?  I've asked you this three times now.  You seem to say it's not showing your `admin.html` page, so what is it doing then?  And, where is the `admin.html` page in your file system?

Comment: @jfriend00 The `admin.html` is inside the folder called "protected".  I act as a user to input username and password to test the login function. The server will only redirect me to stay in the main page (route "/") every time I click the login button after inputting username and password. It cannot redirect me to go to the` admin.html` page.

Comment: I've been having an impossible time understanding what actually happens in the browser when you send `res.redirect("/admin.html")`.  If it ends up at `/`, then that's probably your `isLoggedIn()` middleware failing to detect `req.session['user']`, but you could easily confirm that with a simple `console.log()` there.  It might be the case, that you have to call `req.session.save()` after you add the `.user` property to the session and you may need to wait for the callback on `req.session.save()` before you call `res.redirect("/admin.html")`.